# error Illegal string offset when get data from api lumen

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

i am receiving this error

> "Illegal string offset 'code_room'"

when i get data code_room from api. and I realized this section of code in the file is wrong. however I'm not that great in PHP yet and I am wondering if someone can help me re-write this section to eliminate the error. Thanks!

My code

```
            <?php
            $id_class = $post['id_room_class'];
            $response7 = \Unirest\Request::get($uri.'/room/'.$id_class, $headers); //API URI
            $data7 = $response7->raw_body;    // Unparsed body
            $roomtypeclass = json_decode($data7, true);
            foreach ($roomtypeclass as $get) { ?>
            <button class="btn m-btn--square btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnRoom" onclick="showData2();">
            <?php echo $get['code_room']; ?>
            </button>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you check var_damp($roomtypeclass); ?

Answer (score 1):

The **illegal offset** means that the index your are referencing does not exist. So, in this case the 'code_room' index of the array is probably not defined. To prevent the error, change this line:

```
<?php echo $get['code_room']; ?>
```

to below code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($get['code_room']) && !empty($get['code_room'])) {
        echo $get['code_room'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: its work, but the data code room is not showing. I wonder why?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($get)` or `print_r($get)` and check if it has any data/value for `code_room`

Comment: It's not an array. You need to use `$get->code_room`. Try it out.

Comment: Answering this question, in this way, is a duplicate.  Questions like these hit SO at least a dozen times per day and they are all closed the same way.  I will look for this duplicate on my phone, but you are welcome to help.